FastAPI app throws ModuleNotFound error on startup
I created a monorepo containing my frontend and my Python backend. When trying to start the FastAPI server hosting my GraphQL Endpoint I get:
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'backend.
Any help is appreciated.
Structure
My monorepo contains my frontend and other files in my root folder (Poker). The Python backend is located in the backend folder. The structure looks like this:
poker
├── src
├── venv
└── backend
    └── src
        ├── main.py
        ├── __init__.py
        └── api
            ├── schema.py
            ├── query.py
            └── __init__.py

main.py
from fastapi import FastAPI
from strawberry.fastapi import GraphQLRouter
from backend.src.api.schema import schema

app = FastAPI()

graphql_router = GraphQLRouter(schema, path="/", graphql_ide="apollo-sandbox")

app.include_router(graphql_router)

query.py
import strawberry

def get_hello():
    return "Hello world"

@strawberry.type
class Query:
    hello: str = strawberry.field(resolver=get_hello)

schema.py
import strawberry
from backend.src.api.query import Query

schema = strawberry.Schema(query=Query)

Error
When I try to start the server from /backend with uvicorn src.main:app --reload, FastAPI throws:
/backend/src/main.py", line 3, in <module>
    from backend.src.api.schema import schema
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'backend'

I tried to change the imports in main.py and schema.py to "api.schema" to no avail.

Im following this example by the apollo foundation

Moving schema.py and query.py into the src folder didn't work either

If you are running main.py from within backend/ then your import should be from src.api.query import Query. As a side note you might want to restructure your project and have the main script at the root of your project, it's much easier that way and avoids most import errors or having to manually modify the python path

When resolving imports, Python relies on the PYTHON PATH. It is a list of several directories in which Python looks for the modules or packages you attempt to import.
By default, it contains the directory from which you executed your script (in your case /backend) and several other standard directories, for instance the one which pip modules are installed (among others).
If you try to import backend.src.api.query, Python is going to try to locate the a package named backend in every of the folder present in the PYTHON PATH. And it is going to fail, as it would require / to be in the path instead of /backend (since in your case, it basically tries to find a folder named backend in /backend).
Solution
There are several ways to tackle this issue.
You can rely on relative imports, instead of absolute imports (as you are using now).
Instead of from backend.src.api.schema import schema, you can use from .api.schema import schema.
Relative imports behave similarly to relative path in a filesystem, where . refers to the current location (in this case the backend.src package, since the main.py file is in the /backend/src package). And api is indeed a sub-package of backend.src (subfolder in /backend/src).
If you want to stick with absolute imports, the correct import in your case would be:
from src.api.schema import schema
since in your PYTHON PATH you have the /backend folder, you must start the import path form the backend package.
Finally, you could also update your PYTHON PATH to include the parent directory of backend, but I would not recommend this approach.

I deleted all files and created them again. IntelliJ fixed my imports and it all works now. The import statements look like this:  from api.schema import schema - I have no clue why it works now but it does
